# Image URLs after SSL configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssl

Any has experience implementing SSL for image URLs?

My understanding is the Portfolio Base URL will change to HTTPS but the base and image URL should path stay the same. For example:

Before SSL implementation

- Portfolio Base URL: http://image.company.com/lib/randomnumber/a/3
- OLD Image URL:
  http://image.company.com/lib/randomnumber/a/3/24a02c19-d971-41f7-845e-149222f97748.png

After SSL implementation

- Portfolio Base URL: https://image.company.com/lib/randomnumber/a/3
- NEW Image URL:
  **https**://image.company.com/lib/randomnumber/a/3/24a02c19-d971-41f7-845e-149222f97748.png

Is this your experience?

Basically we want to make sure the OLD image URLs will still load (assuming HTTP-HTTPS redirect works on recipient's email client) while we are updating all the emails to use the NEW HTTPS link. Also, the pervious emails using OLD image URLs will continue to load.

I am getting contradicted info from Support. They suggested

> the image link it won’t change

but I will have to

> re-upload the assets after the SSL configuration

I don't understand why I will need to re-upload the assets if the image links won't change?!

Or is this is correct and I have overlooked something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through this a few times and this is what happened for me:

The image links will not change for the HTTP version, but they also will not be updated to use HTTPS after the SSL is configured.

Any new images you upload after the SSL in configured will automatically use HTTPS.

So if you are happy for existing images to remain HTTP, then do nothing. If you want all existing images to now use HTTPS, you need to re-upload them, at which point they get a new SSL link, meaning you need to update any existing references with the new SSL link.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This is very helpful!

Comment: SFMC Support finally applied the SSL to the server. Just want to give an update to this. Our old images have automatically migrated to HTTPS, but the image is still accessible via HTTP so it did not affect any emails we have already sent and we can take our time to update our templates. Newly upload images has the same behaviour - get a HTTPS URL but can load via HTTP.